# html5 canvas fillRect stored in variable

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Can I store `fillRect` to a variable? After which cut a rectangle out using variable `'c'`? besides having to write `fillRect` twice.

```
var c = ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the in-built functions, but as an alternative you can do something like this

```
var c = function() {
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}
```

And then to invoke it twice:

```
c();
c();
```

Comment: @Phrogz: Can you help me with the "twice"?

Comment: hmm.. but right now I drew a big rectangle over my canvas. Then I want to cut small rectangle out of it without cutting whats on my canvas already (meaning to operate on the big rectangle only, not whats below the big rectangle). Is there anyway to do it? or can i store the big rectangle in a variable to manipulate with it?

Comment: @user1407415 This changes your question completely. You should ask a new question describing this clearly (what you _want_) and delete this question (which appears to describe one way that you thought you might _implement_ what you actually wanted).